# Can LESS be used with visualforce pages reliably?

Tags: salesforce, less, visualforce

I would like to use the new [Bootstrap library from Twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for an external site hosted on Force.com. I really like the idea of using [LESS to compile the CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#compiling), but I'm uncertain if I'll run into any issues since I'm unaware of how to set the stylesheet's `rel=` using VisualForce or override the `<head>` so that I can just set it manually.

Here's the LESS javascript compile syntax:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/path/to/bootstrap.less">
<script src="/path/to/less.js"></script>
```

Has anyone else had success with LESS in a VisualForce page, or can you confirm that it will work without issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used it myself, but that should be VF-compatible. That said, I'd recommend against using the JS compiler for less except during development - there's no reason not to use the compiler to generate vanilla CSS and save your users an extra download + compile step.

Comment: When using the JacaScript compiler during development, does the `rel` type need to be `stylesheet/less`?

Comment: No, because compiled LESS is purely native CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I want to determine the most efficient LESS workflow in VF before marking as accepted, but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: Most efficient for you as a developer is certainly using the syntax you listed above. I'm fairly certain that would work with VF in (at least most) modern browsers. But using that approach at runtime, to me, is just asking for trouble - native CSS is going to be one less moving part for you to debug if you run into problems and there is no end-user value-add to using the client-side compiler.

Comment: Agreed. Given the compile latency of VF/APEX it's nice to have other options, but you're right that it makes sense to precompile for production.  Thx for the feedback.